# xmrMiner does not detect RX 580 gpus

Tags: miners

I'm new to xmr mining on Windows and yet to find some decent miners.

I'm trying xmrMiner but it only detects GTX  gpu on my pc.

I'm wondering how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not an expert about miners, but taking a quick look to xmrminer in github site, its says that its a CUDA-based miner for xmr. CUDA is the platform used by Nvidia cards, so dont expect it to work properly with your Rx.

Being said that, you have plenty of options about choosing a proper miner.

Do you have only amd or mixed amd-nvidia cards? you can try the new xmr-stak which will recognize both platforms (CUDA for Nvidia and Opencl for amd).
https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/releases
If you are willing to try it, i recomend you to try both 2.0 and 2.1 releases, and use the one which gives you better results.

Also, there is claymore cryptonote miner, xmr-stak-amd, and others, but i think those are the most popular.

If you are using windows and will try the new xmr-stak, and dont want to use CPU for mining, make a batch file "xmr-stak.exe --noCPU". I hope this helps. Kind regards...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tested both xmr-stack-wn64 2.0 and 2.1. 2.0 crashed but 2.1 detected both NVIDIA and AMD and now is warming my room :)

Comment: If you want to go deeper about fine tuning, check mining tag about the proper settings for each card (block-threads for nvidia and intensity-worksize for amd).